# Routes works at the end

Tags: extjs, routes, sencha-touch-2

I need to use routes in my sencha project. But i dont understand why routes work at the end even i write before other. For example,

```
myFunction:function(){
   console.info('hello ')
   this.redirectTo('routingTest',true);   //routes to hash 'routingTest'
   console.info('world. ');
}
-----------
Output:
hello
world.
HI
```

But I want the result as

```
 hello
 HI
 world.
```

=============

Here is my routes:

```
 routes:{
        'routingTest':{
            action:'testing'
        }
    },
    testing:function(){
        console.log('HI')
    }
```

Any ways to solve this problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that console.log is writing to stderr whereas console.info is writing to stdout.

These are different io streams, and may well not come out synchronously.

Update your routing function to use console.info instead

Comment: Actually in routes function, console.log('HI') I need to do more flows  that its console.log here. I want to know about its order.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing second parameter for redirectTo(), you have given it true.

Comment: @PhonSoyang: from piece of code u given, we cant provide info in detail, can you please provide working fiddle, so that we can actually debug it.